# ImportError about PyQt5/QtCore.so while starting mu-editor

Tags: python, pyqt5, linux-mint, mu

I have installed Python 3.6.5, GCC 7.2.0, and mu-editor. While I was tring to start mu-editor, the terminal shows some error messages as follow:

```
seifert@seifert-ThinkPad-T410 /usr/local/bin $ mu-editor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mu-editor", line 7, in <module>
    from mu.app import run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mu/app.py", line 29, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
```

I use the Linux mint 18.02. I believe that it is not a special case, because my friend who also use mint 18.02 met the same unsolved problem. We tried to figure and sovle it few days, but it defeated us obviously...

Please help us, and thank you so much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My friend had provided a set of steps to install mu-editor. Please consider follow:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-pip python-smbus 
sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev 
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev 
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl 
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev 

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz 
tar xf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz 
cd Python-3.7.0/ 

./configure 
make 
sudo make altinstall 

sudo pip3.7 install --upgrade pip 
sudo pip3.7 install mu-editor 

mu-editor
```